# Import XML into SQL where data is defined in place of column ids

Tags: sql, xml, import

I'm struggling to import an XML file into SQL using Visual Studio. Aside from all types of data conversion errors, I get blank tables as a result. Tried using Access XML import feature and I got the same result - blank tables. The problem seems to be with the XML file itself as its data is written into node id fields like in an example below.

```
<SUMMARY ID="BWR1" _Name="MLSummary">
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalBalance" _Value="125" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalUnsecuredBalance" _Value="100" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalCredit" _Value="20" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="Count" _Value="16" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="PublicCount" _Value="0" /> 
</SUMMARY>
```

Ideally I would want this XML to translate into a SQL table with _Name and _Value as columns, so that "TotalBalance", "TotalUnsecuredBalance", 125, 20, etc are values.

```
create test_table ([_Name] nvarchar(max), _Value(int))
```

Could you, please, let me know if you have any ideas on how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure I understand what you're trying to do here....

Try this:

```
DECLARE @input XML = '<SUMMARY ID="BWR1" _Name="MLSummary">
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalBalance" _Value="125" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalUnsecuredBalance" _Value="100" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="TotalCredit" _Value="20" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="Count" _Value="16" /> 
   <_DATA_SET _Name="PublicCount" _Value="0" /> 
</SUMMARY>'

SELECT
    DataSet.value('@_Name', 'varchar(25)') AS 'Name',
    DataSet.value('@_Value', 'varchar(25)') AS 'Value'
FROM
    @input.nodes('/SUMMARY/_DATA_SET') AS Summ(DataSet)
```

This will return a set of rows that look something like this:

```
Name                Value
TotalBalance             125
TotalUnsecuredBalance    100
TotalCredit               20
Count                     16
PublicCount                0
```

Does that help at all? If you have this list of name/value pairs - what do you want to do with this?? Do you have a table you can insert that into? Or do you want to create a table from this?? Not entirely clear on that point....

Comment: Thanks a lot! This approach works for me. I'm just using the output of your select statement to insert into a pre-defined table.